# Python: writing function: how to count average sentence length in any text

Tags: python, string, list

my task is to count average sentence length in a text(with many sentences). I tried two ways, first one like counting tokens in words, but here I don't know how to tell the program, that i want word count in the sentence, and not tokens.

```
def satzlänge(text):
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for x in sentences:
        length = len(x)
        total += length
        count +=1
    avg_length = total / count
    print(total)
    print(count)
    return(avg_length)

print(satzlänge('Hello, this is John. How are you? How is your mother?'))
```

second one I tried to tokenize the sentences in words, but here I get separate lists of words, and I can't add the len(words) together with sum to get the result I need. Error message: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```py
def satzlänge(text):
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    for x in sentences:
        tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
        words = tokenizer.tokenize(x)
        print(words)
        print(len(words))
    avg = sum(len(words))/len(sentences)
    return(avg)

print(satzlänge('Hello, this is John. How are you? How is your mother?'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have sentence and you want to get the number of word in the sentence you can use

```
length = len(sentence.split())
```

Comment: It says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.. thanks anyway

Comment: use this function on the variable x (a sentence), length = len(x.split())